# Ruby on Rails: Passing the selected value of a drop down menu to a function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, devise

I'm using devise and I'm trying to pass the selected value of a drop down menu to a function, but it is not working. The data is being stored in a model called user.

```
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
<%= devise_error_messages! %>
<%= f.select :role, options_for_select([["Job Seeker", "candidate"], ["Employer",  "employer"], ["Recruiter", "recruiter"]]) %>

<% if params[:role] == "candidate" %>
<div><%= f.label :travel %><br />
<%= f.text_field :travel %></div> 
<%  end 
if params[:role] == "employer" || params[:role] == "recruiter"
%>
<div><%= f.label :company %><br />
<%= f.text_field :company %></div>
<% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: is that an exact copy of the code?   you are missing %> after the first end,  and missing <% before the second if.

Comment: Could you post output of html? I need output html from `f.select`. By the way,  `end if`  change to `elsif` ? [rails if else statement](http://railsguru.org/tag/if-else/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me as though your conditionals should use the resource object, e.g. `<% if resource.role == "employer" %>`

You might want to pass the current value for `resource.role` as an argument for `options_for_select`

```
options_for_select([["Job Seeker", "candidate"], ["Employer",  "employer"], ["Recruiter", "recruiter"]], resource.role)
```

It seems to me that you want the user to select a role, then display different fields depending on the selected role. Correct me if I'm wrong. From the portion of code which you posted it's impossible to tell exactly what your approach is. There are several ways to solve the problem including:

1. Post the form with the selected role and re-render the form. The process would be similar to re-rendering forms when there is e.g. a validation error.
2. Break up the form into multiple stages
3. Use javascript to detect when the value of the select has changed and then update the form by showing and hiding fields.